# pad numeric column with leading zeros

Tags: r, number-formatting

I've been looking into this for the past few hours. I have tried using `sprintf` but it changes the column to character. All I want to do is to have a fixed-width numeric column, padded with zeros.

Comment: You can't pad leading zeros without being converted to character class.

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeros. If you want them formatted in a particular way, then you have to convert to a character format.

Comment: uh oh :( OK then thanks yall

Comment: @AlexA., maybe not, since the OP already knows about `sprintf()` ...

Comment: @AlexA. I saw that before posting this. The diff is his variable holds IDs, hence factor or character class would work. but mine is a numeric..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to use a custom class, you can write a print method that does this.  Make a data frame, and give it a custom class:

```
DF <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=sample(c(1, 10, 100), 10, rep=T), c=sample(c(1, 10, 100), 10, rep=T))
class(DF) <- c("my_df", class(DF))
```

Write a print method that uses @BenBolker's formatting:

```
print.my_df <- function(x, ...) {
  num.cols <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  x[num.cols] <- lapply(x[num.cols], sprintf, fmt="%04d")
  NextMethod()
}
```

And then:

```
DF
```

Produces:

```
   a    b    c
1  a 0100 0100
2  b 0010 0001
3  c 0001 0010
4  d 0001 0100
5  e 0001 0001
6  f 0001 0001
7  g 0001 0001
8  h 0001 0100
9  i 0001 0100
10 j 0001 0001
```

You can still use the data frame the same way since the numbers are only converted when they are printed.

```
> sum(DF$b)
[1] 118
```

Answer (score 4):

If you give more context we might be able to help you solve your ultimate (rather than proximal) problem, e.g. if you need *output* in this format but without quotation marks:

```
> cat(sprintf("%04d",5),"\n")
0005 
## or
> print(sprintf("%04d",5),quote=FALSE)
[1] 0005
```

`write.csv(...,quote=FALSE)` might be helpful too

Comment: nice one. but rather than print, I want to save it as a column in a data frame.. everyone says it is impossible..

Comment: @maryam: It is indeed impossible because R stores the _value_ in a data frame, and 1 == 01 == 001, etc. You could always keep your numeric column for calculations, sorting, or what have you and add a character one for display purposes.

Comment: as I keep saying: if you tell us *why* you want to save it as a column in a data frame (which is indeed impossible), perhaps we can give you a different way to solve your problem (e.g. @AlexA.'s answer, which they or I could edit into my answer ...)