# convert a character type column with leading zeros to numeric

Tags: r

I want to convert a character column into numeric column in a data frame.
The column values are like "0001" "0002"...
I used 
as.numeric(as.character(column_name))
it returns 1,2...
but the leading zeros are removed.
I want to keep the leading zeros and change column's type.

Answer (score 3):

If you want leading zeroes, you do not have the option to make it numeric. A numeric class is by definition, logically, numeric, which means leading zeroes would not have any meaning. So you need to decide whether you like to keep it as a character column, OR to convert it to numeric and accept that that leads to a deletion of the leading zeroes.

Comment: Besides this, I could hint you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635379/pad-numeric-column-with-leading-zeros. You might find some methods  there to print numeric values with leading zeroes, while keeping the class numeric.